# How do I convert a 5 or 6 digit decimal to a date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a column that shows the date as a decimal such as 101118 for 10-11-18 and 90118 for 09-01-18. I am trying to create a simple report that would give me all reservations yesterday.

So for example

```
    Select playerid, datereservationmade 
    from dbo.lms
```

normally there is very simple and I would just do

```
    Select playerid, datereservationmade 
    from dbo.lms
    where datereservationmade >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND datereservationmade < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

That does not work in this case because the datereservationmade field is a decimal and if its a month 1-9 it leaves off the 0 and makes it a 5 digit decimal then if its 10-12 it is a 6 digit decimal.

Someone please help me figure out how to convert this!

Comment: Fix the data so dates are stored as dates!  If for some reason -- say an oppressive client -- demands that you store them as strings, then use either YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: You will have to convert this to a `Date` type by converting to varchar and then taking each part based on the ordinal position. Don't forget to add a leading `0` or start working from the right. I would create a reusable function for this.

Comment: You'll have do something like cast it as varchar(6), concat on a leading 0 if it's only 5 characters long, then parse that and rebuild it into your desired date format.  Or, not store dates as non-dates (I know, probably not too helpful...)

Comment: It would give some insight if you described why the data is stored in this manner.  It's unacceptable since it requires 1) transformation- probably to a string, then 2) extraction of the data (such as from DATEFROMPARTS).  In a way, it's a violation of 1NF since the data requires unpacking.The consequence is poor performance as your database churns to make sense of the data.  In terms of storage, the date datatype costs 3 bytes and integers costs 4 so it can't even be argued that the practice is saving memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, you really should fix your schema so that dates are actually being stored as dates. 
If you need to work with the decimal data type, you can use something like the following...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestData; END;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    decimal_date DECIMAL(6, 0) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (decimal_date) VALUES (101118), (90118), (101718);

--==============================================

SELECT 
    td.decimal_date,
    dd.date_date
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), td.decimal_date), 6)) ) cd (char_date)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(cd.char_date, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'), 1)) ) dd (date_date)
WHERE 
    dd.date_date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the decimal to varchar(6) by adding a zero in front and getting the RIGHT 6 characters.

Then convert the string to a date from its parts, which are substrings in your varchar(6).   This is made easier in SQL Server 2012 with the [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DATEFROMPARTS, as Tab Alleman suggested, you might get something like this:

```
-- Example of the arithmetic
SELECT 101118 / 10000 AS Month, (101118 % 10000) / 100 AS Day, (101118 % 100) AS Year
-- Using the math in DATEFROMPARTS
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS((101118 % 100) + 2000, 101118 / 10000, (101118 % 10000) / 100 )
```

However, I'm skeptical that you've provided all the correct information. What happens on January first? Your decimal value won't start with zero (as you stated). Will your day always pad with zero? If not, then 1119 won't produce the same result as 10119. If, however, your day does start with zero, then the equation above should work fine.